# Using Low Search

Tags: low-search

Hi Was wondering if anyone can help me?

I have purchased Low Search and im stuck.

Basically the ultimate goal is to have a channel called franchise with say 200 different franchises/entries, with a textarea field in each filled with different postcodes seperated by a comma in each entry.

for example one entry would be:

Title: Conwy

Postcodes: ll21, ll22, ll23, ll24, ll25

At somepoint i may need to have a postcode more indepth for sameple ll21 5bd.

These are the postcodes that, that franchise covers.

I want to have the search only search the channel "franchise" and only searches the "postcode" field.

For the results i just want to go straight to the relevant entry.

Honeslty i really appreicate any help. Because i am so stuck.

Thanks,

Wes.

Hi Low,

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="search/results" required="keywords" search:postcodes_covered}
 <fieldset>
<label for="keywords">Enter your postcode:</label>
<input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Enter your postcode here" class="postcode-entry" />
<span class="postcode-error">{error_message}</span>
<button type="submit" class="white-button postcode-button"><span class="fa fa-search icon"></span>Search your postcode</button>
 </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Then the results tag was the bog standard one on the docs.

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="10"}
{if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
<li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
{if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
{if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Sorry for being so Vague, i am just unsure how to go about this, thanks for help.

These are the postcodes in the entry for conwy in the postcodes_covered field:

```
LL16,LL18,LL21,LL22,LL24,LL25,LL26,LL27,LL28,LL29,LL30,LL31,LL32,LL33,LL34,LL57
```

So the idea is that if someone searched for ll26 5he it would return the conwy entry.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you share at least some code you have now? You probably should be looking at either the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords) or the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search).

Comment: Hi Low, i have added to the bottom of the question thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not clear from your question exactly *how* you're stuck, there are a couple of things you can check.

- Using `search:postcodes_covered` in your opening Form tag does nothing. You can remove it.
- You're using `<input name="keywords" ... >`, which means you're using the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords), for which you need to set up at least one [Collection](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/collections#collections).
- When setting up the collection, make sure your postcode field has an assigned weight of 1 or up. Setting it to 0 will exclude it from the index, thus making it not searchable.

You can also consider using the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search). So instead of using `<input name="keywords">`, you'd have to use `<input name="search:my_postcode_field">`.

As for the Results tag: remember that it extends the channel:entries tag. So if no entries show up, that might also be due to a status not being given or the entry/expired dates.

Pro Tip: enable template debugging to see what the add-on is doing. This will help debugging, too.

Comment: Cheers low,

Is it possible to use the "search:field_name:column_name" with matrix but make use of two columns in the search instead of just one.

    search:field_name:column_name_one:column_name_two

Is there a way to take the first column of say "ll28" but then take the second column of "1" or "2" etc.. 

A user would search the <input> for a post code of example "ll28 5he" 

So take "ll28" which would be in column one, and then the second column of sector of "5" and then ignore whatever the user types after that "he"

Comment: I guess this is a different question, really. The syntax you mention isn't possible. You can only target a single column per parameter like that. But you can have multiple parameters.